# dropwizard: How do deal with mappers for queries with joins

Tags: dropwizard

This is more of a design question so I know I'll receive a lot of flak for this but I am a little confused. 
In Dropwizard we use DAO objects to declare the SQL queries we want to run and Mappers for mapping them to the objects.

Existing structure :

```
- StudentPOJO
- StudentMapper for all StudentPOJO fields
- StudentDAO which has all the "select * from student where ..." calls.
```

Change -

```
- StudentDAO now has to have a query that says "Selct a.*, b.name from student a, subjects b where ...."
- Now to get this information I need to 
    - make changes to both Mapper and POJO 
    OR
    - create new Mapper and POJO (or extend the existing POJO and add the new params to the child POJO)
```

What approach is the usual norm for such cases and what are the pros and cons for the same?

Comment: The new query seems not to return a `StudentPOJO` anymore. It dependes on to how you model your domain how this should be handled. Does the query still return a 'student', just with additional attributes? Or does it return something new? Maybe it would help to think about what the `name` of the joined student means.

Comment: Edited my question, not sure how the definition of 'b' got deleted. Yes it doesn't return a pure StudentPOJO anymore it returns student with his major subject name now. So ideally it's not a Student Object anymore but that's where I am confused. This is just one example and there might be multiple such cases. Do I keep creating child objects for each such case? Do I add these attribs to Student and have different constructors for each such case? Or just have a single construcutor that accepts all these multiple params and have diff mappers for each case?